# How to convert messy two letter code into one "two letter" Column TSQL in MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to transpose (I hope the word transpose is correct) a string of letter into a two letter in one column

the data I have is as follows: it is basically a two letter code mixed in together, very messy

```
ColumnID
HG34
HG/WK
HG\34
54/OF
AS\MM
AC54
AC54MM
```

and what I would like to do so to convert above into below:

```
ColumnID
HG
34
WK
54
OF
AS
MM
AC
```

is there a query that can do that?

I don't mind if the result has duplicates as I can always clean it up later

Thank you

Comment: you are trying to separate letters and numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select substring(ColumnID, 1, 2) from your_table
union
select substring(replace(replace(ColumnID,'\\',''),'/',''), 3, 2) from your_table
union
select substring(replace(replace(ColumnID,'\\',''),'/',''), 5, 2) from your_table
where length(replace(replace(ColumnID,'\\',''),'/','')) = 6
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0df81/4)

Comment: You should replace le "/" too, but +1

Comment: thanks I will try that. I guess I can union with more if I need from position 5,2

Comment: Also don't forget about 3rd pair of letters and numbers. Like `MM` in `AC54MM`.

Comment: yes, the first pair will always be in position 1,2. And the third pair. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct substring(col, x*2-1, 2)
from your_table
cross apply (select replace(replace(ColumnID,'\',''),'/',''))c(col)
inner join (values(1),(2),(3))x(x) on len (col) >= x * 2 -- as much pairs as needed
```